# Positioning Screen (Contextual) Help Tabs

Tags: contextual-help

Using the new `WP_Screen` class makes it pretty easy to add help text to a screen.

```
<?php
add_action( "load-{$somepage}", 'wpse_load_reading' );
function wpse_load_reading()
{
    get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
        'id'        => 'my-help-tab',
        'title'     => __( 'My Title' ),
        'content'   => __( 'Help Content' )
    ) );
}
```

This is great for custom pages.  But when adding a help tab to an existing screen, let's say `options-reading.php`, some weirdness happens.

The `load-options-reading.php` hook fires before the built in WP page adds its own help tabs.  In other words, adding a help tab to an existing screen bumps all the built in help tabs to the bottom of the of list.

Here's some code, if you'd like to try this out:

```
<?php
add_action( "load-options-reading.php", 'wpse_load_reading2' );
function wpse_load_reading2()
{
    get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
        'id'        => 'my-help-tab',
        'title'     => __( 'My Title' ),
        'content'   => __( 'Why is this tab above the built in tab?' )
    ) );
}
```

**Is there any way to reorder the help tabs on a screen?**

**EDIT:**

Found a way around this.  The default help tabs are added before the `admin-header.php` file is included.

So you can hook into `load-{$built_in_page}`, and from there hook a function `admin_head` which takes care of setting up your help tabs.

```
<?php
add_action( 'load-options-reading.php', 'wpse45210_load' );
function wpse45210_load()
{
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse45210_add_help' );
}

function wpse45210_add_help()
{
    get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
        'id'        => 'my-help-tab',
        'title'     => __( 'My Title' ),
        'content'   => __( 'This tab is below the built in tab.' )
    ) );
}
```

Seems kind of like a hack.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Mamaduka suggested, you can hook into `admin_head-{$page_hook}` and add the contextual help there.  `admin_head` fires after the default contextual help tabs have been added.

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_head-options-reading.php', 'wpse45210_add_help' );
function wpse45210_add_help()
{
    get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
        'id'        => 'my-help-tab',
        'title'     => __( 'My Title' ),
        'content'   => __( 'This tab is below the built in tab.' )
    ) );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `admin_head-$hook_suffix` action, this is same method just removes exta action and callback.

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* you have three chances:

1. Use `WP_Screen->$_help_tabs` to reorder them manually.
2. Grap the existing help tabs, save them temporarily somewhere else. Then use `WP_Screen->remove_help_tab( $id )` and then add them back in manually.
3. Use the `admin_head` filter to populate the help tabs or missuse one of the filters or hooks that fire before it in admin-header.php

Comment: `WP_Screen::$_help_tabs` is private.  Can't access it directly, unfortunately.  See my edit, I did your third suggestion!